# Jupyter Notebook setup in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2020.1 and I have just started a new project by assigning as the project SDK the python version of the environment I use.

This environment includes, among all others, the following (relevant) packages:

- jupyter
- jupyter-client
- jupyter-console
- jupyter-core
- ipykernel
- ipython
- ipython-genutils

Also, in IntelliJ, I have installed the Python Community Edition plugin.
However, when I want to edit a ".ipynb" file within IntelliJ, I can't see the code split in cells as in the normal Jupyter notebook.

[image: screenshot of non-split ipynb code]

I have double checked everything, and I think that I didn't miss anything it is suggested here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jupyter-notebook-support.html, nevertheless I can't solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Jupyter Notebook Support** is an Ultimate feature, meaning it is available in the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate only.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank you. It's very unfortunate though.